# Laminate or Vinyl (spc)?

Tags: vinyl-flooring, laminate

My wife and I are looking to change our floors from carpet to wood. We got a quote for lvp (spc) for $8200 installed, however another company said because our house is on a hill that vinyl will split and force us to redo all of our floors shortly after. They quoted us $12000 to install a really thick Mohawk laminate. Are we to believe the company that recommended laminate?

Comment: You will probably have bigger problems if being on a hill splits your flooring.  What splits flooring is your sub floor being hilly instead of flat and stiff enough.

Comment: Well, first off, neither of those are **wood**, and second off, pricing is off topic, and third, the house being on a hill makes no difference.

Comment: I cannot even imagine what kind of logic was used to determine that being on a hill will cause the LVP to split!   that may be the biggest bag of bull spit I have heard in a year.

Comment: If your house being on a hill precludes you from using laminate of LVP, the flooring is the least of your problems, methinks.

Comment: Voting to close. The only question seems to ask for speculation on someone else's reasoning with very little supporting information.

Answer (score 1):

Pricing aside, I have used LVP in my own home , rental properties, and installed in many other homes.

It has many advantages over other flooring. Waterproof, can be installed in any room and basements, easy to install, does not need acclimation, will not cup or warp if exposed to water, very resistant to dropped items (pots and pans dropped on the kitchen floor will not cause chips.) easy to clean, can be damp mopped, can be installed over other flooring, ( hard wood and tile.) will last decades.

I would use LVP everywhere. I even put it on an open Lanai.  Still down after a few years and no issues.

Go for the LVP.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking a rigid vinyl plank in the store.  Playing with some open boxes, I found that the locking mechanism seems a lot weaker.  From my imperfectly flat (3/16" hills and valleys on a 10 foot span) I've had a few cracks open up.  NOthing huge.  Under a mm, but visible.

I would expect this to be a bigger problem with the vinyl I've seen.

Vinyl siding has a huge expansion/contraction factor with cold.  We heat with wood, so it's common for the dining room to be 12 C in the morning and 24 C in afternoon with the sun on it.  I don't know this, but I would expect vinyl flooring to have a larger expansion/contraction with temperature changes.  One early plank branded TrafficMaster from Home depot fastened with 1 inch tabs on the edges that were pre glued.  It has opened up badly in the dining room with some cracks up to 3/16

While the vinyl may be waterproof the subfloor is not and the vinyl sheets do not make a water tight seal. With the above mentioned TrafficMasterthere was a corner where the tabs did not cover, allow water to pass thorugh to the subfloor.  When I redo that room, I will have significant subfloor repairs.  In hindsight, I think there is merit in having a ton of small holes throught the subfloor so that when water gets in, it has a way to get out.

They make laminiates and presumably vinyl that are designed to be edge glued.  You run a narrow bead on the exposed edges where your new piece will go.  This takes much longer to install.  I think you need to let each strip bond before doing the next strip.  Getting the right amount of glue is critical.  Too much, and you have squeeze out to clean up.  Too little and you have part of the top layer under the colour and wear layer exposed.  Some of the newer laminates have a waxed edge that will bond with time.  I could see some merit in having a powder similar to bentonite clay that would expand and form a seal if it got wet.

Another potential problem with both types of flooring is heavy weights.  E.g The room where we have had minor separations in laminate has a 600 lb piano at one end and floor to ceiling book cases on one side.  I'm not sure how the floor is supposed to expand and contract under these conditions.

I found one of the laminate floors I did had unequal width planks.  They varied over a range of about 1/16" I went through all the boxes making matched sets so that I could do an entire row with the same width.